# Nesting loops — using the results of one loop, print result, then send result through another loop

Tags: c#, loops, nested, nested-loops, primes

I'm writing a code that takes user input `min` `max` and finds all non prime numbers in that range and display each number. Then I need to display each of those non prime numbers prime factors.

Below is an example for `min = 6 max = 9`:

```
6:2:3   
8:2:2:2   
9:3:3
```

My issue is with nesting my code I think.

```
for (x = min; x <=max; x++)
{
   for (y= 2; y <= (x/y); y ++)
      if (x % y == 0)
       textBox3.Text += x + " : \r\n";
//the above block of code will go through my min max list and display all non primes

   int z;
    for (z = 2; z <= (x/z); z++)
       if (x % z == 0) break;
       if (z > (x/z))
        textBox4.Tex += x + " : \r\n";
  //the above block of code will list all primes between MIN and MAX `
```

My problem is that I need to apply the second block of code only to apply to the result of the first part. I only need to find the prime factors of each non prime between `min` and `max`.

i.e. if the first number in my min max range is 6 (non prime) then that number will be listed then run through the second block and then the prime factors of numbers 1 - 6 will be determined and output.

Sorry for wall of text and probably bad formatting this is my first real attempt at posting here.

UPDATE:

```
  for (x = min; x <= max; x++)
            {
            if (x % 2 == 0 || x % 3 == 0)
                {
                textBox3.Text += x + " : \r\n";
                //returns non prime numbers
                }

                int z;
                for (z = 2; z <= (x / z); z++)
                   if (x % z == 0) break;
               if (z > (x / z))
                    textBox4.Text += x + " : \r\n";
                //returns prime numbers
```

After talking to my professor I have found out that my problem is that my stream of x from the non prime number if statement cant be tracked by the next for loop.

I have to figure out how to link the non prime number x and continue to loop in through the loop that tests for prime numbers and I cant figure out how to make that connection.

Comment: could you be more clear? what output are you expecting from this code?

Comment: Below is an example for MIN = 6 MAX = 9:  
 6:2:3  
 8:2:2:2  
 9:3:3    The first number is the non prime number from the first block of code and the numbers that follow are that numbers prime factors which can be found with the second loop

Comment: Sorry about my formatting in that comment. If you look at the second paragraph an example output is given with a number range from 6 to 9.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to take the result of the first block I have (returns non prime numbers) and for each result run it through the second block ( returns prime factors of that number)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your issue correctly, but did you mean you want to execute the second part of code only if first one is non-prime. Using your code, is this what you would want ?

```
for (x = min; x <=max; x++)
{
   for (y= 2; y <= (x/y); y ++)
      if (x % y == 0) 
        {   // Changed. Second code runs only if non-prime
            textBox3.Text += x + " : \r\n";
            //the above block of code will go through my min max list and display all non primes
            int z;
            for (z = 2; z <= (x/z); z++)
                if (x % z == 0) break;
                    if (z > (x/z))
                        textBox3.Text += x + " : \r\n";
  //the above block of code will list all primes between MIN and MAX `
        } // Changed
}
```

Comment: You understood correctly. So for each non prime found in the first part gets output into a text box then that non prime should be further sorted out into primes from the second part of my code and listed in another text box. However I tried your corrections and it did now work out that way. It looked like it only executed the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Do not cram everything in a single, hard to maintain, method; keep it simple, *extract* method:

```
private static List<int> PrimeDivisors(int value) {
  List<int> result = new List<int>();

  if (value <= 1) // Special case: 1, 0 or negatives: no divisors
    return result;

  for (; value % 2 == 0; value /= 2) // Optimization: even numbers
    result.Add(2);

  int n = (int)(Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.5);

  for (int i = 3; i <= n; ) 
    if (value % i == 0) {
      result.Add(i);
      value /= i;

      n = (int)(Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.5);
    }
    else
      i += 2;

  if (value > 1)
    result.Add(value);

  return result;
}
```

Having this method implemented you can easily fultil the main task:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int x = min; x <= max; ++x) {
   var divisors = PrimeDivisors(x);

   if (divisors.Count > 1) {
     if (sb.Length > 0)
       sb.AppendLine();

     sb.Append($"{x}:{string.Join(":", divisors)}");
   } 
 } 

 textBox4.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Outcome (providing that `min == 6`, `max == 9` and `textBox4` is a Multiline `TextBox`):

```
6:2:3
8:2:2:2
9:3:3
```

Comment: It all looks good, and I've come across things like this on my long quest to figure out how to do this program, but don't hate me when I say its too complicated for me. I havn't learned half of the stuff you posted. I can kind of understand the first part you posted, but I get lost after the second.

Comment: @eran0801: It's quite OK (I've *optimized* the code - `Math.Sqrt`, I've used *string interpolation* - `$"{x}:{string.Join(":", divisors)}"`); the main thing is a *simplification*, *method extraction* in the context: when facing a complex task to do split it into easy ones. Implement and debug `PrimeDivisors` (in any version you like), then use it to achieve your goal.